# React Native: How to turn CSV into readable JSON

Tags: json, react-native

I'm currently using this code to get JSON data so I can use that to map out earthquakes:

```
getEarthquakes(){
  return fetch('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.csv')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) =>{
      console.log(responseJson);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```

I'm using the `.CSV` link because the `.GEOJSON` isn't working.
It's just giving me `ERROR: object object` errors. I've tried finding information but I haven't found anything that has been able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting my emulator, the `.geojson`filled up my console..